# Plotly graph misbehaving in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

When I select options in my Shiny application, I expect it to produce a graph in plotly and it does. It look like this:
[image]

When I unselect the options, it SHOULD look like this:

[image]

However, the output is misbehaving in a way I don't understand why. This is output I get:

[image]
As you can see, the x and y axis still remains. If I hover over the plot with no options selected, the plot still shows the coordinates.
Here is my code:

```
# UI
box(width = NULL, uiOutput("plotTitle"),
plotlyOutput('plot1', height="730px"), collapsed = F, title = "Figure",
status = "warning", solidHeader = T, height = "830px")

# SERVER
output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
   validate(
      need(input$crops, "INSTRUCTIONS: \n\n1) Select Crops Of Interest.\n2) 
        Use 'Farm' tab to refine results.\n3) Hover over graph to see values.")
   )

crop.data <- reactive({
crop.list <- input$crops
z.df <- dat
c.df <- subset(z.df, Crop %in% crop.list)
c.df <- unique(c.df)
})



output$plotTitle <- renderUI({
  if(length(crop.data()) > 0) {
    div(style='background-color:green; color:white; text-align:center; 
          font-size:22px; font-family:"Open Sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif', 
        input$metric)
  }
})

# s.df is the Dataframe
s.df <- subset(s.df, Crop %in% input$crops)

if(length(crop.data()) > 0) {

  if(input$metric == "Percentage") {
    p <- plot_ly(s.df, x = ~Farm, y = ~Percentage, color = ~Crop) %>% 
      layout(barmode = 'stack', xaxis = list(title = ''), margin = list(b = 140))

  } else if(input$metric == "Acreage") {
    p <- plot_ly(s.df, x = ~Farm, y = ~Acreage, color = ~Crop) %>% 
       layout(barmode = 'stack', xaxis = list(title = ''), margin = list(b = 140))

  } else {
    p <- plot_ly(s.df, x = ~Farm, y = ~Exposure_Costs, color = ~Crop) %>% 
      layout(barmode = 'stack', xaxis = list(title = ''), 
              yaxis = list(title = 'Exposure Costs'), margin = list(b = 140))
  }
  p
}
})
```

Is there a specific reason as to why this happens? Also, this error doesn't exist on my local instance but occurs on the shiny server and another's local instance. How do I fix it?

Comment: Try to provide a minimum working example (including dataset). I'd suggest you avoid defining a reactive within another reactive ie. `output$plotTitle` and `crop.data` should be defined outside of the call to `renderPlotly`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `length(crop.data())` to check whether or not to plot but this will return a value greater than 0 for an "empty" data.frame because it is counting the number of columns.

e.g.

```
> (x <- iris[0, ])
[1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> length(x)
[1] 5
```

You really should untangle your mangling of the `reactive`s, `renderUI` and `renderPlotly` but replacing `length(crop.data())` with `nrow(crop.data())` should solve your problem.

This reproducible example shows that your desired behavior does occur for a simple example:

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")

set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]


ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Null Plotly Object"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         checkboxGroupInput("cuts", "Cut", choices = sort(unique(d$cut)))
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotlyOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  plot_dat <- reactive({
    shiny::validate(
      need(input$cuts, "Select a cut")
    )
    d[d$cut %in% input$cuts, ]
  })

   output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
     plot_ly(plot_dat(), x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat, type = "scatter",
             mode = "markers", size = ~carat, text = ~paste("Clarity: ", clarity))
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```